# Brother Driver Asks for IP Address of Network Printer?

Tags: networking, drivers, kubuntu, printing, 18.04

I'm trying to install a `Brother` driver for a printer that is connected to my router's WLAN. The driver asks me for an IP address, which I'm not sure how to give it, and I'm not entirely certain why it is necessary. The driver is from `Brother`'s website

I've chosen the DNSSD option for the printer, and a test page prints, but I have to submit an IP address to finish the driver install.

How can I set up this printer?

`ifconfig` Reveals:

```
eno1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether a0:1d:48:fa:67:c0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 2740  bytes 223080 (223.0 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 2740  bytes 223080 (223.0 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

tun0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.7.7.208  netmask 255.255.255.0  destination 10.7.7.208
    inet6 fe80::3f1a:4fc3:dde6:ae30  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 100  (UNSPEC)
    RX packets 125429  bytes 151411646 (151.4 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 80076  bytes 7343109 (7.3 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vmnet1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.110.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.110.255
    inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fec0:1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 00:50:56:c0:00:01  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 1158  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vmnet8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.50.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.50.255
    inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fec0:8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 00:50:56:c0:00:08  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 1159  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlo1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.1.128  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
    inet6 fe80::82d9:a987:6fc0:ef4a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether e4:70:b8:f8:99:b8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 147190  bytes 183578731 (183.5 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 59747  bytes 16899305 (16.8 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

[image: IP Address Prompt]

Comment: Does your printer have a `Go` button on it?  If it does I read that you should hold that down for 10 seconds it will beep, then print the network configuration page and you should see your IP address for it.

Comment: @Terrance I found that the printer has a feature which displays its IP address.

Comment: So, does the printer have a `192.168.1.xxx` IP address to match your wireless network subnet?

Comment: It has `192.168.001.xxx` Is this normal?

Comment: Yeah, the leading zeros are fine.  You can type them in as the IP it is looking for, or you can leave them out.  Either way should be fine.

Comment: The driver is asking for the printer’s IP address so your computer knows the where to send job data. Did you get it working?